# notify* methods doesn't update RecyclerView's view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

Well I have an app that manages contacts and I use 2 `RecyclerView` to show unselected and selected contacts. The user can select and unselect contacts.

Here's my scenario:

I have those two `RecyclerView`, one for managing selected contacts and other for managin unselected contacts. When a user select a contact from the unselected list, that contact it's removed from that list and inserted in the selected list. The same happens if the user select a contact from the selected list, only that the contact is removed from the selected list and inserted in the unselected list. I have a custom `RadioButton` implemented and in the `onCheckedChanged` event I remove the contact from the appropriate adapter when selected or unselected.

I have one adapter for selected list (`SelectedContactsAdapter`) and another for the unselected list (`UnselectedContactsAdapter`). I use the new `SortedList` collection to manage the data of the adapters and in the callbacks of `SortedList` I notify the adapter of the changes and send a callback message to update the other adapter.

For example, if the user select a contact in the unselected list, in the `onCheckedChanged` event I save the contact before remove it from the adapter (I do this because I need to pass it to the callback so it can be inserted in the other adapter), then I remove that contact from the adapter. That fires the `onRemoved` method of the `SortedList` and there I call `notifyItemRemoved(position)` (with `position` beign the position of the removed contact) and the callback to insert that contact in the selected list.

For some reason the notify* methods doesn't update the `RecyclerView` view. I tried with `notifyDataSetChanged` and it works but it's not an option for me because I need the updates to be fast, almost instant.

I have the 2 `RecyclerView`'s initiated with `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` for FastScroll. Just in case that matters...

Here is my code:

```
public abstract class FilterableContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FilterableContactsAdapter.ContactViewHolder>
        implements Filterable {

    //... Some variables like the filter
    protected Contact mLastContactTouched;
    protected SortedList<Contact> mFilteredContacts;
    protected ContactCallback mContactCallback;
    protected boolean mPropagate;

    public FilterableContactsAdapter() {
        mPropagate = true;
        mFilteredContacts = new SortedList<>(Contact.class, new SortedList.Callback<Contact>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Contact o1, Contact o2) {
                return o1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getName());
            }

            @Override
            public void onChanged(int position, int count) {
                notifyItemChanged(position);
                if(mContactCallback != null && mPropagate) mContactCallback.onContactChanged(mLastContactTouched, position);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean areContentsTheSame(Contact oldItem, Contact newItem) {
                boolean sameIds = (oldItem.getId() == newItem.getId());
                boolean sameNames = oldItem.getName().equals(newItem.getName());
                boolean samePhoneNumbers = oldItem.getNormalizedPhoneNumber().equals(newItem.getNormalizedPhoneNumber());

                if(sameIds && sameNames && samePhoneNumbers) return true;
                else return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean areItemsTheSame(Contact item1, Contact item2) {
                return item1.getId() == item2.getId();
            }

            @Override
            public void onInserted(int position, int count) {
                notifyItemInserted(position);
                /*if(FilterableContactsAdapter.this instanceof SelectedContactsAdapter) notifyDataSetChanged();
                else notifyItemInserted(position);*/
                if(mContactCallback != null && mPropagate) mContactCallback.onContactInserted(mLastContactTouched, position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onRemoved(int position, int count) {
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                /*if(FilterableContactsAdapter.this instanceof SelectedContactsAdapter) notifyDataSetChanged();
                else notifyItemRemoved(position);*/
                if(mContactCallback != null && mPropagate) mContactCallback.onContactRemoved(mLastContactTouched, position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
                notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
                if(mContactCallback != null && mPropagate) mContactCallback.onContactMoved(mLastContactTouched, fromPosition, toPosition);
            }
        });
    }

    public void add(Contact contact) {
        mFilteredContacts.add(contact);
    }

    public void remove(Contact contact) {
        mFilteredContacts.remove(contact);
    }

    //... Some other methods like onCreateViewHolder, the ContactViewHolder declaration and the filter implementation
}
```

```
public interface ContactCallback {
    void onContactInserted(Contact contact, int adapterPosition);
    void onContactRemoved(Contact contact, int adapterPosition);
    void onContactMoved(Contact contact, int from, int to);
    void onContactChanged(Contact contact, int adapterPosition);
}
```

```
public class SelectedContactsAdapter extends FilterableContactsAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ContactViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Contact contact = mFilteredContacts.get(position);

        if(contact != null) {
            holder.parentLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.nameTV.setText(contact.getName());
            holder.phoneNumberTV.setText(contact.getNormalizedPhoneNumber());
            holder.selectCB.setSafeCheck(true, SafeCheckBox.IGNORE);
            holder.selectCB.setOnSafeCheckedListener(new SafeCheckBox.OnSafeCheckedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAlwaysCalledListener(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    contact.setSelected(isChecked);
                    mLastContactTouched = contact;
                    remove(contact);
                }
            });
        } else {
            holder.parentLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class UnselectedContactsAdapter extends FilterableContactsAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ContactViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Contact contact = mFilteredContacts.get(position);

        if(!contact.isSelected()) {
            holder.parentLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.nameTV.setText(contact.getName());
            holder.phoneNumberTV.setText(contact.getNormalizedPhoneNumber());
            holder.selectCB.setSafeCheck(false, SafeCheckBox.IGNORE);
            holder.selectCB.setOnSafeCheckedListener(new SafeCheckBox.OnSafeCheckedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAlwaysCalledListener(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    contact.setSelected(isChecked);
                    mLastContactTouched = contact;
                    remove(contact);
                }
            });
        } else {
            holder.parentLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class ContactsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // init the views and setup the searchbar
        setupMultiContactsPicker();
    }

    //... Some other stuff like an OnClick implementation and 
    //other utility methods that only manage visibility of some
    //components of the UI like 2 TextViews and a ProgressBar



    private void setupMultiContactsPicker() {
        final Filter.FilterListener filterListener = new Filter.FilterListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                updateLayout();
            }
        };

        unselectedContactsAdapter = new UnselectedContactsAdapter();
        unselectedContactsAdapter.setContactCallback(new ContactCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onContactInserted(Contact contact, int adapterPosition) {
                selectedContactsAdapter.setPropagate(false);
                if(selectedContactsAdapter.getItemCount() > 0) selectedContactsAdapter.remove(contact);
                selectedContactsAdapter.setPropagate(true);
                updateLayout();
            }

            @Override
            public void onContactRemoved(Contact contact, int adapterPosition) {
                selectedContactsAdapter.setPropagate(false);
                selectedContactsAdapter.add(contact);
                selectedContactsAdapter.setPropagate(true);
                updateLayout();
            }

            @Override
            public void onContactMoved(Contact contact, int from, int to) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onContactChanged(Contact contact, int adapterPosition) {

            }
        });
        unselectedContacsRV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        LinearLayoutManager uLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ContactsActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        unselectedContacsRV.setLayoutManager(uLayoutManager);
        unselectedContacsRV.setAdapter(unselectedContactsAdapter);
        unselectedContacsRV.setHasFixedSize(true);
        // Initisialize the adapter with the correct contacts (ContactsFilter.UNSELECTED)
        unselectedContactsAdapter.getFilter().filter(FilterableContactsAdapter.ContactsFilter.UNSELECTED, new Filter.FilterListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
                onLoadFinish(); //This method call updateLayout(); when the 2 filters finish to load data into the adapters.
            }
        });

        selectedContactsAdapter = new SelectedContactsAdapter();
        selectedContactsAdapter.setContactCallback(new ContactCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onContactInserted(Contact contact, int adapterPosition) {
                unselectedContactsAdapter.setPropagate(false);
                if(unselectedContactsAdapter.getItemCount() > 0) unselectedContactsAdapter.remove(contact);
                unselectedContactsAdapter.setPropagate(true);
                updateLayout(); // This method show or hide some TextViews that I use as section titles, nothing more
            }
            @Override
            public void onContactRemoved(Contact contact, int adapterPosition) {
                unselectedContactsAdapter.setPropagate(false);
                unselectedContactsAdapter.add(contact);
                unselectedContactsAdapter.setPropagate(true);
                updateLayout(); // This method show or hide some TextViews that I use as section titles, nothing more
            }
            @Override
            public void onContactMoved(Contact contact, int from, int to) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onContactChanged(Contact contact, int adapterPosition) {

            }
        });
        LinearLayoutManager sLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ContactsActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        selectedContacsRV.setLayoutManager(sLayoutManager);
        selectedContacsRV.setAdapter(selectedContactsAdapter);
        selectedContacsRV.setHasFixedSize(true);
        // Initisialize the adapter with the correct contacts (ContactsFilter.SELECTED)
        selectedContactsAdapter.getFilter().filter(FilterableContactsAdapter.ContactsFilter.SELECTED, new Filter.FilterListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
                onLoadFinish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here are some photos of what I'm talking about:

I have one contact selected here:
[image: one_contact_selected_top]
[image: one_contact_selected_bottom]

I have two contact selected here ("Abuela" and "Adela Zapata"):
[image: two_contacts_selected_top]
[image: two_contacts_selected_bottom]

And here, on the left, I have unselected the first item I have selected (the contact "Abuela"). On the right is the list with all contacts unselected:
[image: first_contact_unselected]
[image: unselected_list]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally after a week of research I have found the solution... Magically I suspect that `setHasFixedSize(true)` has something to do with the view doesn't get resized or repainted even that the items were updated... After I remove that line from the 2 adapters configuration all work very well... It's funny that I figure out the solution hours later than I posted the question.